# How to prevent Doctrine2 from cascade persisting an entity on event

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Let's say I have a simple entity EstablishmentEntity, with a ManyToOne relationship on $employee that looks like this :

```
namespace Msm\CeopBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Msm\CeopBundle\Entity\Establishment;

/**
 * Establishment
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="establishment")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class School
{

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Professionnal", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="teacher_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true) 
 */
private $employee;
```

My problem : that entity is used for different kinds of establishments and has a lot more useful attributes in my code (I kept it simple for my question). One kind of establishement won't have any employees. Is it possible to tell Doctrine/symfony NOT to cascade persist the employee in that perticular case after class instanciation for example ?

So far it automatically persists an empty employee entity when creating an establishment, which is ok for most establishments but not all...

Comment: you can remove cascade persist and export $em->persist($employee) into your logic

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't thought about that...was looking for something complicated. Just to be sure, there is no other way ? Say, if there are really many linked entities to be persisted and persisting all of them in many actions becomes tedious ?